# Can a property in OWL be objectProperty and datatypeProperty at the same time

Tags: xsd, owl

I want to denote the following xs:simpleType from XSD in OWL:

```
<xs:simpleType name="test">
    <xs:union memberTypes="xs:normalizedString">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:normalizedString">
          <xs:enumeration value="123"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="456"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:union>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

I use equivalentClass to denote xs:enumeration:

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="testEn">
        <owl:equivalentClass>
            <owl:Class>
                <owl:oneOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about="testEn_123"/>
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about="testEn_456"/>
                </owl:oneOf>
            </owl:Class>
        </owl:equivalentClass>
    </owl:Class>
```

And link xs:normalizedString and the equivalentClass with `unionOf`.

xs:normalizedString couldn't be expressed as Class in OWL, right? So I have a property that is objectProperty and datatypeProperty at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in OWL 2 DL, see https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-new-features/#F12:_Punning

> ...However, OWL 2 DL still imposes certain restrictions: it requires that a name cannot be used for both a class and a datatype and that **a name can only be used for one kind of property**. ...